# Set array to variable in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

New to groovy and not a java lover.  In my [jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/), I'm having an issue with doing what I think would be simple.

```
SURL = new String[3]
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{ 
   url="value"
   SURL[i]="${url}"
}
```

Seems like in this simple example that SURL[0] through SURL[2] would be set to "value". I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thx!

Comment: Jenkins pipeline is not really a plain groovy- The error you get is related to pipeline behavior

Comment: as @doelleri said it you are trying to assing GString to a String variable while in fact you dont need to use GString according to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a pretty contrived example, I'm not sure what you're really trying to do.

If `url` is already a `String` why not add it directly to `SURL`? Putting it in `"${}"` gives you a `GString`instead.

It's not very Groovy to use a statically typed String array, just use a list.

```
def SURL = []
3.times {
    SURL << url
}
```

This example uses the overloaded `<<` operator to append to the list.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up setting it as a string like this:

```
SURL[i]="${url}" as String
```

Still unsure why it's functioning this way.  Maybe thinking it's an object?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it right, consider to define the array type explicitly. Instead of

```
def SURL = new String[3]
SURL[ 0 ] = "-- $a" // << here comes ArrayStoreException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
```

do

```
String[] SURL = new String[3]
SURL[ 0 ] = "-- $a"
```

then it runs smoothly and groovy can properly outbox the `GString` value to `String`.